# Magento Order for community version

Tags: magento

I am facing problem that I want to upload a file with/while placing an order from frontend.
i.e. how to upload a file with an order from frontend in magento?
Here I am using Community version CE 1.9.

Please help me friends.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

during product creation you can use custom attribute with input type ***file***.

follow the direction and fill up title and input type field.

```
catalog -> manage products -> add product -> continue -> custom options -> add new option
```